# "Checked' in HTML radio button with background image and select image does not work

Tags: php, html, css, forms, radio-button

Here is what I have

HTML Code

```
<input class="rad_a"  type="radio" name="answer" value="1" checked="checked">
```

CSS Code

```
.rad_a:before {
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
content: '';
position: absolute;
background-image: url(images/option_a.jpg);
pointer-events: none;
}

.rad_a:checked:before {
background-image: url(images/selected.png);
}
```

Here is how it looks.

[image]

The problem is the checked attribute doesn't work.

I put

```
 <input class="rad_a"  type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
```

or

```
 <input class="rad_a"  type="radio" name="answer" value="1" checked="checked">
```

The same result (its not showing selected, instead it is showing the option_a.jpg, I want is that if I put checked in the radio button it should show selected.png (completely blackout) and the value of it going in $_POST.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you make your background image for `checked` `!important`?

Comment: You could do this with Java Script, but I don't think that's very efficient. Just for the JS lovers out there .

Comment: This should not work to begin with, since input is a replaced element that doesn't have any children. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before _"Note: The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to replaced elements such as <img>, or to <br> elements."_ You should apply formatting to a _sibling_ of the input, based on the input state. Go research that, there's enough explanations of the technique out there.